# How can I call one same function for multiple textfields in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a text field editing func to reset corner radius and border color. I've seven text fields in my project. Now I want to call this function for all text fields with short code.

This is how I've written my code:

```
textField1.editFunc()
textField2.editFunc()
textField3.editFunc()
textField4.editFunc()
textField5.editFunc()
textField6.editFunc()
textField7.editFunc()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
[textField1, textField2, textField3, 
 textField4, textField5,textField6,textField7].forEach { $0.editFunc() }
```

**OR**

```
view.subviews.forEach {
  ($0 as? UITextField)?.editFunc()
}
```

**OR**

Create outlet collection and link all textfields to it

```
 @IBOutlet weak var allF:[UITextField]!
```

Then

```
allF.forEach { $0.editFunc() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom textfield class to customise:

```
class RoundedUITextField: UITextField {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.editFunc()
    }
    
    func editFunc() {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: CustomTextField!
```